# How to retrieve values from the last row in a DataTable?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, datatable, datarow

I am having problems retrieving values from the last inserted row in a Data-table. I have a login form and the values will be inserted in the  table has the ID (int,an auto incremented value), userID (int), logintime (smalldatetime) and logouttime(smalldatetime). The code which is used to inside the login button,it thus inserts all values except the log out time

```
DateTime t1 = DateTime.Now;
objbal2.insertLoginTime(s, t1);
```

and in the log out button I am updating the table, so I have to retrieve the last row values. I am updating the table with reference to the ID value and userID.
Can I use this query get the values? But I can't figure out how?

```
SELECT COLUMN FROM TABLE ORDER BY COLUMN DESC
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: So, after the login of one user there are no more logins until the previous user logout?

Comment: Your problem is not clear to us... Kindly make it easy to understand

Comment: @steve. other users can log in.bt once a user login i immediately want to get that value of the row.so that i can pass the same values to the update query

Answer (score 39, accepted):

if you have to read the values from last row then

```
DataRow lastRow = yourTable.Rows[yourTable.Rows.Count-1];
```

will return you last row. and you can read the values from it.

My second guess is that by datatable you are referring to table in sql server.

Then with small modification your query is fine as well.

```
SELECT TOP 1 COLUMN FROM TABLE ORDER BY COLUMN DESC
```

Comment: And yet, when I update the database I receive this error:

SqlDateTime overflow. Must be between 1/1/1753 12:00:00 AM and 12/31/9999 11:59:59 PM.

Comment: it means that your datetime object is getting the min value

Answer (score 9):

```
var dt = new DataTable();
dt.AsEnumerable().Last();
```

`dt.AsEnumerable()` returns an `IEnumerable<DataRow>`

Answer (score 1):

You can got the value from your session and then update your database as per your change

```
DateTime t2 = DateTime.Now;

DataRow Row = Mylagin_dataTable.Rows.Count-1

Row[0]["LogoutTime"] = t2 ;
```

if your **ID in session** then use below

```
DateTime t2 = DateTime.Now;

DataRow Row = Mylagin_dataTable.Select("LoginID='"+ HttpContext.Current.Session["loginID"] + "'");

Row[0]["LogoutTime"] = t2 ;
```

Comment: And yet, when I update the database I receive this error:

SqlDateTime overflow. Must be between 1/1/1753 12:00:00 AM and 12/31/9999 11:59:59 PM.

Comment: what is your datatype in sqlserver ? datetime , datetime 2 or smalldatetime. you need to assign as respective value

Comment: lets check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11829070/datetime-now-into-smalldatetime
you will got the answer :)

Comment: have you converted DateTime.Now to small datetime Cindrella ??

Answer (score 0):

Execute following query on Application Exit event, this will do your work

`string _query = string.Format("update top 1 SessionTable set LogOutTime = {0}  where UserID = {1} order by ID desc", DateTime.Now, UserID);`